# Direction of change plot in 2 images taken from video

Tags: plotting

I have two successive images from a video and I would like to plot the largest direction of change from the first image to the second image as a vector plot.

For example, if image 1 was {{0,1,2},{0,3,4},{0,0,0}} and image 2 was {{1,2,0},{3,4,0},{0,0,0}}, we can see that the segment {{1,2},{3,4}} is moving leftwards, so the vector plot would have at positions {1,2},{1,3},{2,2},{2,3} a vector {-1,0}.

How can this be achieved in Mathematica... assume that image 1 is called data1 and image 2 is called data2.

Comment: See `ImageFeatureTrack[]`

Comment: Is there a way to make ImageFeatureTrack work on an array of values rather than an image. My data is basically a matrix of values.

Comment: You already asked 26 questions, accepted only 4 answers and voted only 6 times. Please try to participate more!